# How to concatenate two items from different lists using python?

Tags: python, list, tuples

How can I concatenate two items from different lists, together, if I have lists like this:

```
data_list = [['Toys', 'Communications', 'Leather'], ['Teddy', 'Mobile', 'Hand'], ['bear', 'phone', 'bag']]
```

I have used zip function to convert them into tuples like this:

```
data_tupled_list = zip(*data_list)
```

which results like this:

```
[('Toys', 'Teddy', 'bear'),
 ('Communications', 'Mobile', 'phone'),
 ('Leather', 'Hand', 'bag')]
```

I want a list like this:

```
[('Toys', 'Teddybear'),
 ('Communications', 'Mobilephone'),
 ('Leather', 'Handbag')]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're most of the way there:

```
data_tupled_list = [(x[0],x[1]+x[2]) for x in zip(*data_list)]
```

It might be a little more pretty if you unpack the tuple:

```
data_tupled_list = [(a,b+c) for a,b,c in zip(*data_list)]
```

And it would *definitely* be prettier if you could give `a`,`b` and `c` more meaningful names.

Comment: I'd go further and use ''.join((b, c)) to avoid nasty concatenation performance in a list

Comment: @GoingTharn -- There's no reason to use `''.join((b,c))` over `b+c`.  Join needs to create a tuple and then concatenate it in basically the same manner that `b+c` does.  If you have more than 2 elements, you might get a little gain -- An certainly for arbitrary length you want `join`.  But for the case where you only have 2 elements, I suspect that `+` is as performant as you can get.

Comment: is that true even though you're in an implicit loop w/the list comprehension? I've always assumed (perhaps wrongly!) that the concatenate inside a loop/list comp is not performant

Comment: @GoingTharn -- There is no difference between `a+b` in a comprehension compared to outside the comprehension.  (same with `''.join(...)`)

Comment: @ mgilson: What if I don't know the index of the field, I want to concatenate with? data_list is populated by retrieving the values of a dict, and as dict is not order specific therefore it is impossible for me to know the index of the field. . .

Comment: @ mgilson: For suppose if I have a dictionary like this `a = {'date' : ['2012-03-09', '2012-01-12', '2012-11-11'], 'rate' : ['199', '900', '899'], 'counrty code' : ['1', '2', '44'], 'area code' : ['114', '11', '19'] and so on. . .}` and then I use zip func `zip(*a.values())`, now Please tell me How can I concatenate the 'country code' with 'area code'?

Comment: @RoBErT -- Unfortunately, that's a much more difficult problem.  Since dicts are unordered, you have no way of knowing which value is `country code` and which is `area code`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice way to write this in Python3

```
>>> data_list = [['Toys', 'Communications', 'Leather'], ['Teddy', 'Mobile', 'Hand'], ['bear', 'phone', 'bag']]
>>> [(x, ''.join(args)) for x, *args in zip(*data_list)]
[('Toys', 'Teddybear'), ('Communications', 'Mobilephone'), ('Leather', 'Handbag')]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd operate on it in two parts; you really want to do the following:

```
data_list = [['Toys', 'Communications', 'Leather'], ['Teddy', 'Mobile', 'Hand'], ['bear', 'phone', 'bag']]
groups = data_list[0]
predicates = data_list[1]
suffixes = data_list[2]

combined = [ ''.join((pred, suff)) for pred, suff in zip(predicates, suffixes)]
finalresult = zip(groups, combined)
```